# Why use KeyDataset instead of dataset directly in HuggingFace Pipelines

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

Example from link: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/pipelines#pipeline-batching

Example:

```
from transformers import pipeline
from transformers.pipelines.pt_utils import KeyDataset
import datasets

dataset = datasets.load_dataset("imdb", name="plain_text", split="unsupervised")
pipe = pipeline("text-classification", device=0)
for out in pipe(KeyDataset(dataset, "text"), batch_size=8, truncation="only_first"):
    print(out)
```

Why should one use `KeyDataset` instead of calling the dataset directly as follows:

```
for out in pipe(dataset["text"], batch_size=8, truncation="only_first"):
    print(out)
```